# Karate: Is there a way to match responses from different scenarios

Tags: match, karate

I have 2 scenario outlines created in a feature file and have 2 responses from each. I need to match the responses of each scenarios to each other. Is it possible?

I tried asssigning the responses to different objects using '*def object = response' and then I used And match object1 == object2. Expected to match the both objects and give me wheather they are same or not.

Comment: no you cannot. before you proceed, read the linked q&a very carefully